# Query all Tables in Database in MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How would I be able to make a list of tables and traverse them in php?

I tried to figure out how the mysqli_query would output, but I keep getting an error.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysqli_select_db($link,$name);
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW TABLES");
echo $result;
```

Essentially I want to be able to place them in an array and traverse the array going through each single table and do a quick query on them.

Thanks for the help.

edit: title

Comment: What is this error you are getting exactly?

Comment: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string" and this is pertaining to the line "echo $result;"

Comment: don't do show tables. use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` db. that's what it's there for.

Comment: First you must read the [PHP manual pages for mysqli_* functions](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: @Palladium: Nearly all questions on SO could be solved by reading docs and searching the net, but that would defeat the purpose of Stack Overflow. The OP has obviously tried something and had a problem with it. That's why we're here.

Comment: @Palladium tried reading the php documentation, doesn't really go into depth about the result unless im missing something, ill take another look

Comment: @Herbert lol funny thing when I googled my problem, a lot of the links let me to stackoverflow too. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `$result` is not a string, but a [MySQLi result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

Use something like

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    /* Process $row here ... */
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Much easier than tossing it into an array and then traversing it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
$tables = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW TABLES");
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !== null)
{
        $tables[] = $row[key($row)];
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was describing, but rodion's solution is much simpler. thanks for the input though!